# Using indexPathForItemAtPoint on collectionView with transformed cells

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having an issue grabbing indexPaths of collection view cells after I transform their attributes to rotate the cell by a certain angle.  I understand adding a transform doesn't actually change the frame - which is why I'm assuming indexPathForItemAtPoint/cellForItemAtIndexPath is returning incorrect index/cell.

Basically I have a UIView that hovers at certain points of the screen, and I'd like to select the cell it hovers over. But since the transform doesn't effect the frame - the calculations are off.  I'm looking for a creative way to remedy this in my layout.

Using CollectionViewDelegate's didSelectRowAtIndex works surprisingly well, but unfortunately its not very helpful in syncing this view that hovers around the screen (would make the movement choppy).

My layout code is very similar to Apple's CircleLayout code from last years's WWDC with the addition of that transform -

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:path];
    attributes.size = CGSizeMake(ITEM_SIZE, ITEM_SIZE);

    attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x +_radius * cosf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount + M_PI / 2),
                                    _center.y + _radius * sinf(2 * path.item * M_PI/ _cellCount + M_PI / 2));

    //Rotate the item the correct amount
    attributes.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(SOME_RADIAN);
    return attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the rotation is the same for each cell, then you could think outside the square (rectangle) and treat the hovering UIView as though it is in an alternate coordinate system, then apply the inverse transformation to its frame before attempting the indexPathForItemAtPoint and cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```m
CGAffineTransform inverseAffine = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-SOME_RADIAN);
//  use the inverse to move the hover UIView into the original coordinate space
CGRect hoverInOriginalSpace = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(hoverView.frame, inverseAffine);
CGPoint midpoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(hoverInOriginalSpace), CGRectGetMidY(hoverInOriginalSpace));
NSIndexPath *path = [collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:midPoint];
...
```

**UPDATED:**

If the rotation is not constant (for example if it depends on the index of the cell) then you need to do a scan:

```m
- (UICollectionViewCell *)findCellUnderHover:(UICollectionView *)collectionView hover:(UIView *)hoverView {
    NSArray *visibleCellIndexPaths = [collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
    for (NSIndexPath *path in visibleCellIndexPaths) {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:path];
        CGFloat rotationForCell = ...;
        CGAffineTransform inverseAffine = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-rotationForCell);
        //  use the inverse to move the hover UIView into the original coordinate space specific to this cell
        CGRect hoverInOriginalSpaceForCell = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(hoverView.frame, inverseAffine);
        CGPoint midpoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(hoverInOriginalSpaceForCell), CGRectGetMidY(hoverInOriginalSpaceForCell));
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(cell.frame, midpoint))
            return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the rotation isn't exactly the same for each cell =/  It uses its indexPath.row as a multiplier.  Wish I specified that more in the original post.